# MAXDOP not working?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, parallelism, maxdop

I wanted to test out `MAXDOP` on my computer. So I set `MAXDOP` to 2 for a specific query. However, when I looked at my logical processors in Task Manager as I ran the query, it looked like they were all being used. I thought that it would only be using 2 logical processors if `MAXDOP` was set to 2? Does anyone know what is happening? Please see image below.

Another issue is, the `DOP` returned by the execution plan said 1. Now I know that setting `MAXDOP` does not mean SQL Server will actually use the number set. However, given that it seemed all my 4 logical processors were being used to process the query, it made it even more strange to see `DOP` 1.

This is the query I ran:
[image]

This was what happened as I ran it (i.e. it looks like all 4 logical processors are being used to run the query):
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The query is a non-parallel (serial) plan so it is definitely executing from start to finish on a single SQL Server [worker thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178626.aspx), associated with a single SQLOS [scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177526.aspx).

From an operating system perspective, this single thread is still subject to Windows' normal scheduling algorithms by default. I say "by default" because the behaviour depends on the setting of the [CPU affinity mask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187104.aspx).

By default, the mask is all zeroes, meaning Windows can choose on which physical execution unit (e.g. core) to run the thread per timeslice. When the CPU affinity mask is set to 1 for the scheduler concerned, the scheduler is bound to a specific physical processing unit at all times.

So, a SQL Server thread running at 100% will tend to hop around physical units, leading to a "smeared out" pattern. When the affinity mask is set, you will see a cleaner spike in activity because Windows is not allowed to move the thread around.

All that said, the pattern you see in Task Manager is not a great way to look into SQL Server's CPU activity. SQL Server is not the only process running when your query executes - you are also seeing CPU usage by SSMS receiving results and writing them to the screen, for example.

SQL Server provides a range of [dynamic management objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176083.aspx) to look at things like schedulers, workers, and threads. There are [even more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx) for looking at the status of current sessions, requests and so on.

In case these concepts are new to you, see the TechNet article, [SQL Server Batch or Task Scheduling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189267.aspx) and related content.

> *Another issue is, the DOP returned by the execution plan said 1*

The `MAXDOP` query hint only limits the total number of schedulers a query might use. At compilation time, the optimizer may decide between a serial and a parallel plan, based on cost estimations. For a very simple `SELECT` query such as the one in the question, the optimizer will usually choose a 'trivial' execution plan, which never uses parallelism.

Comment: Paul, thanks a lot for this answer! It also answers my old question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55245/utilizing-a-single-core-to-100-doesnt-show-in-perf-mon-as-single-cpu-being-ful

Comment: @EdwardDortland I had seen that question before - judging by my upvote - but had forgotten about it. At the time, I didn't answer because the existing one seemed to cover it. If I helped clarify things with this answer, that's a bonus! Thanks for alerting me :)